# Calculating idiosyncratic risk of stock without beta or risk free rate

Tags: capm, beta

I have been given the expected returns and standard deviations of 2 stocks A and B, as well as the standard deviation of the market portfolio and correlation between security A and the market portfolio. I am asked to determine the idiosyncratic risks of both A & B as well as the value of Beta for B given it is positive.

I am finding it difficult to calculate the idiosyncratic risk of B without its covariance, correlation, or the risk-free rate or expected return of the market.

Answer (score 1):

Check out page 24 of Active Portfolio Management (mine is Second Edition) if you can get your hands on it. Problem 3 is effectively this exact problem. Or see here:

[Calculating the correlation of stock A with stock B](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29546/calculating-the-correlation-of-stock-a-with-stock-b)

This should be all the tools you need to solve it!